# Is there any way to turn off the "loading" message when a page refreshes in Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have a report that auto-refreshes every 30 seconds.  Usually this happens fast enough that you don't even notice.  Sometimes, however, the load takes a bit longer.  When this happens, the existing data is "greyed out" a bit, and a animated box that says "Loading" appears.

Is there any way to prevent the data from beign "greyed out"? I find it very distracting.

The report is part of a monitoring tool.  We have it on a jumbo-tron.  Under certain conditions, it changes color, which catches people's attention.  The "greying out" also catches people's attention but for the wrong reason.

Comment: what version of ssrs, and how are you doing the refresh? with the built-in "refresh every ... seconds"?

Comment: SSRS 2008R2, built-in refresh every 30 seconds.  When I look at the code of the webpage, I can see "WaitControlBackground" class, with some configured values.  I just wish I could find the same thing in BIDS.

Comment: In BIDS, it should be under the top menu Report / Properties / General; at least for 2005, I think they moved it for 2008 but it's in the same general area IIRC. I don't get the "loading" with my instance, even when refreshes take forever.

Comment: In 2008, open the properties window (F4), and click in the whitespace of the design panel, AutoRefresh is under Other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an ASP.NET developer on hand, have them use the ReportViewer control to embed the report directly into a plain old aspx page. I've done this to a few reports, and they never show the usual "Report is being generated" message that you get when accessing them via Report Manager. (You might have to set AsyncRendering="False" on the ReportViewer control to get the desired behavior.)

This will also allow you to dress up the page a bit, and conceal the various Reporting Services toolbars, which would be ideal for a billboard display like you describe. Put a meta refresh in the page to get a 30-second refresh, and you're set.